# - SolidWorks API - View outline and inner boundaries

Tags: api, solidworks

I am working on the SolidWorks app to detect if the view overlaps or not. If we use the view outlines to detect if the view overlap or not is not always correct. 
as shown below. 
[image]

I would like to get the outline for the inner rectangle show in the diagram. The swView.getOutline gives the rectangle that is much bigger than the original view. 
as shown below.

[image]

Comment: I have no direct answer for your problem but maybe a workaround. You could use the View.GetLines4() method to get the start and end points of the visible lines of your view. Then calculate the min/max points which span the box.

Comment: @Sinue Thank you,  Make sense, I will try and update if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following [View Scale Macro](https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-api/document/drawing/views-size-based-scale/). I manage to find the approximate inner rectangle.  It's not the best solution, whereas it's not complex and it's not with heavy computation like other available solutions

```
double[] outline = view.GetOutline();
  outline[0] += BorderWidth;
  outline[1] += BorderWidth;
  outline[2] -= BorderWidth;
  outline[3] -= BorderWidth;
```